# Is there an elegant way to activate a tab in which a focused widget is located?

Tags: c++, events, qt, user-interface

I have a QLineEdit inside a widget inside a QTabWidget. Let's say that tab is at tab index 2. When currently active tab is at index 1, and I call setFocus() (and show(), and raise()) on the QLineEdit, the active tab doesn't switch to index 2 to show the focused widget.

Is there any elegant way to show the focused widget's tab when that widget gets focus?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a more generic function to switch to the tab containing a widget:

```
void SwitchToTabContaining(QTabWidget * tabsW, QWidget * w)
{
    for(int i=0;i<tabsW->count();++i) {
        QWidget * tab = tabsW->widget(i);
        if(tab->isAncestorOf(w)) {
            tabsW->setCurrentWidget(tab);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not tested but you should get the idea of how it works.

Comment: This works good enough, but is there a way to make it more generic - to accept arbitrary nested tab widgets?

Comment: That will be a totally different approach. Accept this answer then post another question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `QTabWidget` is named qtab:

In the QLineEdit's `focusInEvent`:

```
QTabBar* bar = qtab->tabBar();
bar->setCurrentIndex(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

And for your specific case, where you're sure the QLineEdit is a child of one of your tab widgets:

```
myTabWidget->setCurrentIndex(myTabWidget->indexOf(myLineEdit->parentWidget()));
```

Comment: The line edit widget may not be a direct child of the tab widget.

Comment: Agreed, this is a solution to just the specific given case.  I like your general solution.